# Mousepad and keyboard freeze

Tags: keyboard, mouse, freeze

I have a brand new Asus P55VA laptop. From time to time at random moments the mousepad and the keyboard freeze for about 1 second. If there is an external mouse or keyboard attached then this external keeps working even if the normal keyboard is frozen. I'd exclude a hardware problem because i tried a Linux live CD and it was working properly. I have also tried formatting and changing OS (from 7 to 8) and it was working fine at first. Then after Windows started updating and getting to its current up to date status it stopped working again. All drivers are up to date and taken from the Manufacteur'S homepage.

What can i do to solve this upsetting problem?

Comment: I would contact ASUS for assistance in the matter.  Since its brand new its under warranty.

Comment: i would like to keep that option as the latest. every time i had to do with computer support i only had trouble and we need this computer for work so i am not really into sending it away for a few weeks. But thanks for the suggestion. any idea is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried an earlier version of the driver for this device?